# How can I reload new JSON data from the same site in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, refresh

basically i am making an app that pulls a number from online (using json) and what i want to know is how i can reload that data every 5 seconds or so. I have set it up so it is in a function called getData() and i thought making it in an infinite while loop would work like this: 
`while 1 > 0 { 
    getData()
    sleep(5)
}`
However, whenever i launch the app it crashes. (It works when i call getData() without the infinite loop) Am i missing something? How can i refresh my json data every 5 seconds? Thank You!

Comment: Never use `sleep()` or an infinite loop as that will block the thread. If you must poll, use a `Timer()`

Comment: How would i go about setting up a timer? and would that refresh the data?

Comment: The [`Timer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer) just executes a function when it "ticks"; you could reload your data in that function.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from these you can use:

```
var timerDispatchSourceTimer : DispatchSourceTimer?
```

you can call your function in ViewWillAppear and set the delay as you want:

```
timerDispatchSourceTimer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: [], queue: DispatchQueue.main)
timerDispatchSourceTimer?.scheduleRepeating(deadline: .now(), interval: .seconds(YOUR DELAY TIME))
timerDispatchSourceTimer?.setEventHandler{
            // do something here
  self.performSelector(inBackground: #selector(YOUR FUNCTION), with: nil)
        }
timerDispatchSourceTimer?.resume()
```

and on viewwillDisAppear:

```
timerDispatchSourceTimer?.cancel()
```